# How to build many-to-many relations using SQLAlchemy: a good example

Tags: python, many-to-many, sqlalchemy, associations

I have read the SQLAlchemy documentation and tutorial about building many-to-many relation but I could not figure out how to do it properly when the association table contains more than the 2 foreign keys.

I have a table of items and every item has many details. Details can be the same on many items, so there is a many-to-many relation between items and details

I have the following:

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    description = Column(Text)

class Detail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Detail'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    value = Column(String)
```

My association table is (It's defined before the other 2 in the code):

```
class ItemDetail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ItemDetail'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    itemId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Item.id'))
    detailId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Detail.id'))
    endDate = Column(Date)
```

In the documentation, it's said that I need to use the "association object". I could not figure out how to use it properly, since it's mixed declarative with mapper forms and the examples seem not to be complete. I added the line:

```
details = relation(ItemDetail)
```

as a member of Item class and the line:

```
itemDetail = relation('Detail')
```

as a member of the association table, as described in the documentation.

when I do item = session.query(Item).first(), the item.details is not a list of Detail objects, but a list of ItemDetail objects.

How can I get details properly in Item objects, i.e., item.details should be a list of Detail objects?

Comment: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html is very verbose and lots of examples. Not sure what else is needed here.

Comment: Association proxy was not what I was looking for. I replaced the ItemDetial class declaration with a Table one and used the secondary parameter in relation function

Answer (score 71):

From the comments I see you've found the answer. But the SQLAlchemy documentation is quite overwhelming for a 'new user' and I was struggling with the same question. So for future reference:

```
ItemDetail = Table('ItemDetail',
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('itemId', Integer, ForeignKey('Item.id')),
    Column('detailId', Integer, ForeignKey('Detail.id')),
    Column('endDate', Date))

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    description = Column(Text)
    details = relationship('Detail', secondary=ItemDetail, backref='Item')

class Detail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Detail'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    value = Column(String)
    items = relationship('Item', secondary=ItemDetail, backref='Detail')
```

Comment: Not sure why, but in my case I had to add `Base.metadata` to the `ItemDetail` Table, as described [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many).

Comment: @Kerma I have another problem. how to put the relation in the same Class instead of put it In Item class and Detail Class seperate??

Comment: In my case, I had to actually **remove** the `Base.metadata` in order to remove the "FK associated with column..."

Comment: umm, so how do you create new details and associate them with the right items?

Comment: Exactly the same way as it did in the regular databases

Answer (score 37):

Like Miguel, I'm also using a Declarative approach for my junction table. However, I kept running into errors like

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: secondary argument <class '**main**.ProjectUser'> passed to to relationship() User.projects must be a Table object or other FROM clause; can't send a mapped class directly as rows in 'secondary' are persisted independently of a class that is mapped to that same table.

With some fiddling, I was able to come up with the following. (Note my classes are different than OP's but the concept is the same.)

### Example

Here's a full working example

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, Session

# Make the engine
engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", future=True, echo=False)

# Make the DeclarativeMeta
Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    projects = relationship('Project', secondary='project_users', back_populates='users')


class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = "projects"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    users = relationship('User', secondary='project_users', back_populates='projects')


class ProjectUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = "project_users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    notes = Column(String, nullable=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    project_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('projects.id'))



# Create the tables in the database
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Test it
with Session(bind=engine) as session:

    # add users
    usr1 = User(name="bob")
    session.add(usr1)

    usr2 = User(name="alice")
    session.add(usr2)

    session.commit()

    # add projects
    prj1 = Project(name="Project 1")
    session.add(prj1)

    prj2 = Project(name="Project 2")
    session.add(prj2)

    session.commit()

    # map users to projects
    prj1.users = [usr1, usr2]
    prj2.users = [usr2]

    session.commit()


with Session(bind=engine) as session:

    print(session.query(User).where(User.id == 1).one().projects)
    print(session.query(Project).where(Project.id == 1).one().users)
```

### Notes

1. reference the table name in the `secondary` argument like `secondary='project_users'` as opposed to `secondary=ProjectUser`
2. use `back_populates` instead of `backref`

I made a detailed writeup about this [here](https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/many-to-many-relationships-in-fastapi/).

Comment: Have you tryed: 
```secondary=ItemDetail.__table__```
or
```secondary=ItemDetail.__tablename__```

Comment: Incomplete answer throws an error

Comment: @AdnanFayaz Please provide more details--what error is thrown and what version of Python and SQLA are you using? This works for me on Py 3.110.rc1 with SQLA 2.0.2

Answer (score 11):

Previous Answer worked for me, but I used a Class base approach for the table ItemDetail. This is the Sample code:

```
class ItemDetail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ItemDetail'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    itemId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Item.id'))
    detailId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Detail.id'))
    endDate = Column(Date)

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    description = Column(Text)
    details = relationship('Detail', secondary=ItemDetail.__table__, backref='Item')

class Detail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Detail'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    value = Column(String)
    items = relationship('Item', secondary=ItemDetail.__table__, backref='Detail')
```

Comment: Using this approach I get the following error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: secondary argument <class> passed to to relationship() Activity.participants must be a Table object or other FROM clause; can't send a mapped class directly as rows in 'secondary' are persisted independently of a class that is mapped to that same table.` which leads me to believe that mapped classes can't be used as a secondary attribut

Comment: It would need to be `secondary=ItemDetail.__table__`